# Calling HttpClient and getting identical results from paged requests - is it me or the service?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I am sending five  HttpClient requests to the same URL, but with a varying page number parameter.  They all fire async, and then I await for them all to finish using Tasks.WaitAll().   My requests are using System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

This mostly works fine, and I get five distinct results representing each page of the data about 99% of the time.

But every so often, and I have not dug into deep analysis yet, I get the exact same response for each task.  Each task does indeed instantiate its own HttpClient.  When I was reusing one client instance, I got this problem. But since I started instantiating new clients for every call, the problem went away.

I am calling a 3rd party web service over which I have no control.  So before nagging their team too much about this, I do want to know if I may be doing something wrong here, or if there is some aspect of HttpClient ot Task that I'm missing.

Here is the calling code:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        page = load_made + i;
        var t_page = page;
        var t_url = url;
        var task = new Task<List<T>>(() => DoPagedLoad<T>(t_page, per_page, t_url));
        task.Run();
        tasks.Add(task);
      }
      Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Here is the code in the DoPagedLoad, which returns a Task:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
 var results = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result();
```

I would appreciate any help from folks familiar with the possible quirks of Task and HttpClient

NOTE: Run is an extension method to help with async exceptions.

```
        public static Task Run(this Task task)
        {
            task.Start();
            task.ContinueWith(t => 
            {
                if(t.Exception != null)
                    Log.Error(t.Exception.Flatten().ToString());
            });
            return task;
        }
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the `page` variable is changing before the `Task` actually begins. If the `page` variable is a variable that is passed by value (int, short, etc..), then it shouldn't matter but if it's passed by reference (string, object, class) then it could create the race condition you are seeing. I would try capturing the value of page inside `DoPageLoad` to see if it's what you expect

Comment: *"When I was reusing one client instance, I got this problem. But since I started instantiating new clients for every call, the problem went away."* - So are you having this problem with your old code only, or with your new code (where you create a new `HttpClient` for each request).

Comment: There really is no reason for this to happen when reusing an `HttpClient`, unless you're doing something wrong (changing [`BaseAddress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?view=netframework-4.8) on each call maybe?) The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) says that it "is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads."

Comment: Do not create multiple `HttpClient` instances - you're doing something wrong, find that and fix that. Creating too many clients may exhaust system resources. You're also calling it synchronously - you should almost never touch `Task.Result` but use `await` when starting an async operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a definitive answer because we don't have all the detail but here's a sample implementation of how you should fire off HTTP requests. Notice that all async operations are awaited - `Result` and `Wait` / `WaitAll` are not used. You should almost never need / use any of those - they block synchronously and can create problems.

Also notice that there are no global cookie containers, default headers, etc. defined for the HTTP client. If you need any of that stuff, just create individial HttpRequestMessage objects and add whatever headers you need to add. Don't use the global properties - it's a lot cleaner to just set per-request properties.

```
// Globally defined HTTP client.
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

// Other stuff here...

private async Task SomeFunctionToGetContent()
{
    var requestTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
    var responseTasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Fake URI but still based on the counter (or other
        // variable, similar to page in the question)
        var uri = new Uri($"https://.../{i}.html");

        requestTasks.Add(_httpClient.GetAsync(uri));
    }

    await (Task.WhenAll(requestTasks));

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var response = await (requestTasks[i]);

        responseTasks.Add(HandleResponse(response));
    }

    await (Tasks.WhenAll(responseTasks));
}

private async Task HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    try
    {
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            var content = await (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            // do something with content here; check IsSuccessStatusCode to
            // see if the request failed or succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something when no content
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you I will try this out and let you know the result